# Insert current date and time is 23 hr 59 min 59 sec

Tags: sql-server

I have two fields in a table: `Transaction_Fromdate` and `Transaction_Todate`.
I need to insert current date in `Transacion_Fromdate` and Current date with 23 hr 59 min 59 sec in Transacion_Todate`

For example:

> Transaction_Fromdate :2015-12-18 20:59:51.940
>
> Transacion_Todate :2015-12-18 23:59:59.940

Comment: have you tried using the INSERT statement?

Comment: Please provide some code examples of what you have tried so far so that we can help you answer your question.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define an interval. Rather than define it as "closed-closed" (i.e. defining both endpoints explicitly), define it as "closed-open" (i.e. define starting endpoint, but the set will include everything less than the ending endpoint). Said more succinctly, define it as start <= interval < end rather than start <= interval <= end. You'll save yourself some headaches later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today's date only:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
DECLARE @TodayEnd DATETIME

-- Today: 
SET @Today = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

-- End of today:
SET @TodayEnd = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Today))
```